# Ayuda con GoogleSheet al leer Datos desde Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

En el metodo **readAll()** estoy intentando sincronizar lo que tengo en mi BD/firebase en mi hoja de calculo en GoogleSheet, no es igual que el metodo para ingresar datos agradezco cualquier ayuda para retornar los datos..!!

```
function readAll(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GCq47PHvI8tXUVgR6YgWUb4J-6npGzZwg8QiwC5J_II");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DtaExample";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var dataFirebase = base.getData();
  var sheetData = sheet.setActiveRange(dataFirebase);
  sheetData();
}
```

Aqui ingreso los datos desde googlesheet al ejecutar el metodo **writeDataToFirebase()**
Funciona perfecto con **updateData()** para ingresar los datos porque con setData modifica lo que exista previo en la base de datos.en el metodo 
**writeDataToFirebase()**

```
function writeDataToFirebase() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1GCq47PHvI8tXUVgR6YgWUb4J-6npGzZwg8QiwC5J_II");
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var dataToImport = {};
  for(var i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
    var firstName = data[i][0];
    var lastName = data[i][1];
    dataToImport[firstName + '-' + lastName] = {
      firstName:firstName,
      lastName:lastName,
      emailAddress:data[i][2],
      country:data[i][4],
      department:data[i][5],
      weight:data[i][6],
      birthDate:data[i][7]
    };
  }
  var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DtaExample";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  base.updateData("", dataToImport); 
}

function getAllData() {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/DtaExample";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();
  for(var i in data) {
    Logger.log(data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName);
  }
}
```

Comment: `FirebaseApp` no es un servicio incluido por lo que debería indicar cómo lo has declarado (por ejemplo, usando una "librería"). Por otro lado no está claro sobre la pregunta. Si tu código genera un error indica textualmente que error es.

Comment: Por supuesto amigo se debe conocer Google Apps Scripts para saber de lo que hablo FirebaseApp efectivamente es una libreria el ejemplo lo tome de aqui: https://sites.google.com/site/scriptsexamples/new-connectors-to-google-services/firebase/tutorials/read-and-write-data-in-firebase-from-apps-script y aqui se implementa la libreria FirebaseApp en el script de google

Comment: Modestia aparte, lo sé. De todas formas deberías incluir en la pregunta la mención de que estás usando la librería indicada en el enlace, particularmente porque algunos en lugar de agregar la librería "original" crean su propia copia. También deberías indicar la versión de la librería usada o si la estas usando en modo desarrollador. Justo ayer yo tuve que hacer una copia de otra librería publicada en el mismo sitio, ObjApp, porque App Maker no me aceptó la original (lo curioso es que la FirebaseApp si la aceptó).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que encontre una solucion por ahora funciona sin problemas mi problema era que no encontraba como agregar la data que obtenia de firebase lo encontre en:
**https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets** y ademas encontre como retornar datos desde Firestore por si alguien puede servirle:

Firestore for Google Apps Scripts-**https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript#creating-a-service-account**

Firestore Method Documentation
-**https://github.com/grahamearley/FirestoreGoogleAppsScript/wiki/Firestore-Method-Documentation#getdocuments**

```
function getAllData() {
  var firebaseUrl = "https://my-roodent.firebaseio.com/Users";
  var base = FirebaseApp.getDatabaseByUrl(firebaseUrl);
  var data = base.getData();
  for(var i in data) {
    //Logger.log(data[i].firstName + ' ' + data[i].lastName);
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.appendRow([data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude,data[i].especieC]);
  }
}
```